# Page gets slower after adding dynamic view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```js
app.directive( 'addDonation', function ( $compile ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            donors:"="
        },
        template: '<p class="btn btn-default" ng-click="add()">Add</p>',
        controller: function ( $scope, $element ) {
            $scope.add = function () {
                var el = $compile( '<donation-directive donors="donors"></donation-directive>' )( $scope );
                $element.parent().append( el );
            };
        }
    };
});
```

attached is the code which gets executed as the user clicks on a button say "add", after the template gets appended to the view the whole page gets heavier and starts responding slow :(

Comment: look at the timeline in chrome dev tools.  Look for any heavy CSS like shadows etc, and js anything that might add extra paints like scroll event etc. or obviously leaks and all that too.

Comment: What is donors? maybe the problem is what donation-directive is doing with that value?. Also you could try to avoid the $compile call by using an ng-repeat in the template

Comment: Nah I didn't find any thing complex there..
@SebastianPiu Donors is just a flag I'm passing for click Handler.